# Excel: Matrix formula - Why isn't matrix (vector) returned?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a matrix formula which is basically `SUM` with nested `N` function. The `N` function returns matrix (vector) which is summed by `SUM` function and everything works as expected.

`{=SUM(N(A1:A5=1))}`

Evaluation steps:

1. `=SUM(N({1,1,2,3,3}=1))`
2. `=SUM(N({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}))`
3. `=SUM({1,1,0,0,0})`
4. `=2`

But when I tried to use `N` function separately with same parameters (as matrix formula), no matrix (vector) is returned anymore.

`{=N(A1:A5=1)}`

Evaluation steps:

1. `=N(A1:A5=1)`
2. `=N(1=1)`
3. `=N(TRUE)`
4. `=1`

Why?

*PS: I have non-English version of Excel. Some names could be translated inaccurately.*

Comment: Or maybe more trivial: `{=A1:A5}` returns vector with values `{A1,A2,A3,A4,A5}`. But `{=N(A1:A5)}` returns only value of `A1`.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006937/using-excel-n-function-with-arrays

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Excel 2013. I read question 32006937, it's interesting thing (using a unary plus), but I afraid it is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the function is returning an array, but is only *displaying* the first item because it only has one cell (so far).

To display the rest of the returned array in Excel 2013, you need to **drag the formula down to be the same length as the input array**.

In the latest version of Excel, this is not necessary.

I have simulated this earlier behavior in my version (Excel 365) with the @ symbol. You can omit it in your version:

[image]

Of course at this point, you may as well just use

```
=N(A1=1)
```

And drag that down instead.

EDIT: I should probably add that to achieve the result of counting how many 1s there are, why not just use this:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,1)
```

Comment: Oh, of course. So, `Evaluate formula` shows only data which are valid for selected cell (only one cell could be selected while evaluating) and shows data related for this cell only. In `B1` is only the first value of result array`{=N(A1:A5=1)}` => only data for this cell are evaluated (same as for `=A1=1`). In other hand `SUM` sums all data from array, and whole array is shown in evaluation steps. Right?

Comment: I don't use `COUNTIF` because I found this behavior when I tried to compose complex nested formula. Here I used as simple example as possible. :)

Comment: That's right. It's a limitation of earlier versions but once you know...