# Excel matrix formula has to return matrix (vector), but returns single (scalar) value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Yes, I read: [Excel: Matrix formula - Why isn't matrix (vector) returned?](https://superuser.com/questions/1568762/excel-matrix-formula-why-isnt-matrix-vector-returned) but this is not the same.

Basically I can't figure out why is formula like this: `{=MATCH({1,2,3},{1,2,3},0)}` which usually returns matrix (vector) `{1,2,3}` returns a single value.

**Consider this example:**
*Note: There is very long introduction - an interesting part starts below bold text: "Until now everything works as expected."*

There is a Table with `Name` and Revision `columns`.

- I want to have for each unique Name one unique integer number `GroupNo`.
- Then add to the `GroupNo` a decimal part `RevPart` according to revision value
  (`""=0, "a"=0.01, ...`)
- `GroupNo+RevPart` is called `FullGroupNo` (`FGN`)
- I want to know know the max `FGN` for each Name group: `MaxInGroup` (`MIG`)

This could be easily done using multiple columns in the table (`Table1`):

```
GroupNo:     =MATCH([@Name],[Name],0)
RevPart:     =INDEX({0,1},MATCH([@Revision],{"","a"},0))/100
FullGroupNo: =[@GroupNo]+[@RevPart]
MaxInGroup: {=MAX(([@GroupNo]=[GroupNo])*[FullGroupNo])}

Table1
+------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
| Name | Revision | GroupNo | RevPart | FullGroupNo | MaxInGroup |
+------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
| A    | =""      |       1 |       0 |           1 |       1,01 |
| A    | a        |       1 |    0,01 |        1,01 |       1,01 |
| B    | =""      |       3 |       0 |           3 |          3 |
| C    | =""      |       4 |       0 |           4 |       4,01 |
| C    | a        |       4 |    0,01 |        4,01 |       4,01 |
+------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
Note: ="" means there is a blank string in the cell (formula ="")
```

The `FullGroupNo` (`FGN`) could be obtained in one formula referencing only `Name` and `Revision` columns.

```
FGN_2: {=(INDEX({0,1},MATCH([@Revision],{"","a"},0))/100+MATCH([@Name],[Name],0))}
FGN_2 is a new column in the table (Table1) above. It's matrix formula returns single (not-matrix) value.
 
Area under FGN (Matrix) is an ordinary worksheet range. This whole area contains return (matrix) value.
FGN (Matrix): {=INDEX({0,1},MATCH(Table1[Revision],"","a"},0))/100+MATCH(Table1[Name],Table1[Name],0))}

Table1     Just range
+-------+  +--------------+
| FGN_2 |  | FGN (Matrix) |
+-------+  +--------------+
|     1 |  |            1 |
|  1,01 |  |         1,01 |
|     3 |  |            3 |
|     4 |  |            4 |
|  4,01 |  |         4,01 |
+-------+  +--------------+
```

Now I tried to consolidate `MaxInGroup` in a single matrix formula.

```
Original MaxInGroup formula:
MaxInGroup:  {=MAX(([@GroupNo]=[GroupNo])*[FullGroupNo])}

Step1
- replace[@GroupNo] with matrix formula with reference only to Name and Revision columns
MIG_1:       {=MAX((MATCH([@Name],[Name],0)=[GroupNo])*[FullGroupNo])}

Step2
- Replace (matrix) [GroupNo] with matrix formula with reference to Name and revision columns
MIG_2:       {=MAX((MATCH([@Name],[Name],0)=MATCH([Name],[Name],0))*[FullGroupNo])}
```

**Until now everything works as expected.**

```
Step3
- Replace (matrix) [FullGroupNo] in MIG_2 with matrix formula with reference to Name and Revidion columns
  (so, basicaly I need formula from FGN (Matrix) used before

MIG_3:  {=MAX((MATCH([@Name],[Name],0)=MATCH([Name],[Name],0))*(INDEX({0,1},MATCH([Revision],{"","a"},0))/100+MATCH([Name],[Name],0)))}
Note: MIG_3 is part of the Table1 so column names only are enough

So now we could have same values in MaxInGroup, MIG_1-3 columns. But no. We haven't.
The RevPart in MIG_3 depends only on the firs Revision value.

+------+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name | Revision | MaxInGroup | MIG_1 | MIG_2 | MIG_3 |
+------+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| A    | =""      |       1,01 |  1,01 |  1,01 |     1 |
| A    | a        |       1,01 |  1,01 |  1,01 |     1 |
| B    | =""      |          3 |     3 |     3 |     3 |
| C    | =""      |       4,01 |  4,01 |  4,01 |     4 |
| C    | a        |       4,01 |  4,01 |  4,01 |     4 |
+------+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
Versus
+------+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name | Revision | MaxInGroup | MIG_1 | MIG_2 | MIG_3 |
+------+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| A    | a        |       1,01 |  1,01 |  1,01 |  1,01 |
| A    | a        |       1,01 |  1,01 |  1,01 |  1,01 |
| B    | =""      |          3 |     3 |     3 |  3,01 |
| C    | =""      |       4,01 |  4,01 |  4,01 |  4,01 |
| C    | a        |       4,01 |  4,01 |  4,01 |  4,01 |
+------+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
Note: ="" means there is a blank string in the cell (formula ="")
```

Comment: This seems awfully complicated for something so simple. Are you definitely using Excel 2013? :)

Comment: @FlexYourData Yes it's definitely Excel 2013. What do you think is so simple there? (The part with multiple columns? Yes, I agree. But there is need for doing it in a single formula.)

Comment: I say it's simple because we're really just trying to do with several complex steps what the `MAXIFS` function does in one. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

Comment: That said, I was able to replicate your issue. Not sure what the problem is, I'll think on it a bit more today.

Comment: Yes, newer Office versions are good, but I must maintain compatibility with 2013 at least until end of its support period (2023).

Comment: Ok. Good luck then.